# Get the type of a Class property in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I'm creating a dynamic query on Grails. The UI will pass a JSON Object that holds all the criteria. I manage to do that:

```
def criteria = params.criteria

def l = DomainClass.createCriteria().list {
    for(int k = 0; k < criteria.names().length(); k++) {
        def names = list[x].names()
        if(DomainClass.hasProperty(names[k])) {
            eq(names[k], list[x][names[k]])
        }
    }
}
```

This works already if all the properties of `DomainClass` is type `String`, but I also use other types such as `Long` and `Date` so I want to implement something like this:

```
def criteria = params.criteria

def l = DomainClass.createCriteria().list {
    for(int k = 0; k < criteria.names().length(); k++) {
        def names = list[x].names()
        if(DomainClass.hasProperty(names[k])) {
            if(/* DomainClass.getProperty(names[k]).getClass() == Long */) {
                // Parse first string to long before actually using it to the criteria
                eq(names[k], Long.valueOf(list[x][names[k]]).longValue()))
            }
            else if(/* DomainClass.getProperty(names[k]).getClass() == Date */) {
                // parse first date
                ...
            }
            else {
                // The default criteria
                eq(names[k], list[x][names[k]])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know in Java nor in Groovy what to use to the condition in the `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you could approach this

```
instanceof
```

or

```
object.getClass().equals(Float.class);
```

With your example you could do something similar

```
if(DomainClass.getProperty(names[k]).getClass().equals(Date.class))
```

[Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174966/example-of-%C2%B4instanceof%C2%B4)

Answer (score 1):

Exact match

```
new Long(1L).getClass().equals(Long.class)
> true
```

or

```
new Long(1L) instanceof Number
> true
new Long(1L) instanceof Long
> true
```

Your `==` approach (with added `.class`), should also work, since it is unlikely, that there are two different Long classes are loaded but I would prefer the `equals` way.

```
new Long(1L).getClass() == Long.class
> true (most likely)
```

Comment: In Groovy, `==` always calls `equals()` if the lef-side is non-null. You should not use `equals` in Groovy.