# Android: Getting list of views by tag and changing specific button

Tags: android, object, button

I am writing a custom calendar, my calendar is a Grid View that contains a button for each day with a onClick Listener on every button. Each has a tag representing a date.

**I am needing to find the button in a layout by specific tag(date) and then work with it (change its contents to bold)**

So, first, I am getting all the views that match the tag(event date):

```
 /**
 * Get all the views which matches the given Tag recursively
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920559/how-to-find-list-of-views-that-has-a-specific-tag-attribute
 * @param root parent view. for e.g. Layouts
 * @param tag tag to look for
 * @return List of views
 */
public static List<View> findViewWithTagRecursively(ViewGroup root, Object tag){
    List<View> allViews = new ArrayList<View>();

    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
    for(int i=0; i<childCount; i++){
        final View childView = root.getChildAt(i);

        if(childView instanceof ViewGroup){
            allViews.addAll(findViewWithTagRecursively((ViewGroup)childView, tag));
        }
        else{
            final Object tagView = childView.getTag();
            if(tagView != null && tagView.equals(tag))
                allViews.add(childView);
        }
    }

    return allViews;
}
```

Next I am trying to make a button from that view and set its text to bold

```
Log.d(tag, "calendarFormatdate  "+eventDate);
List gridcells = findViewWithTagRecursively(calendarView, eventDate);

if (gridcells.size() == 1) {
  Button gridcellButton = gridcells.get(0); //this doesnt work(required Anroid.Widget.Button - FOUND Java.Lang.Object 
  //Object gridcellbutton =  gridcells.get(0); //this works but cannot assign it to Button object
  }
```

I understand that Button and Java Object are different, **but it there any way to convert this object to button to use as I am showing?** Object gridcellBUtton value is the following:

```
renaldyalisys D/GridCellAdapter: object value android.widget.Button{eb9b3a4 VFED..C. ........ 0,0-68,72 #7f0c00bc app:id/calendar_day_gridcell}
```

Comment: Way too much going on in your Question. I suggest you cut this back to the essentials, the bare minimum to show your problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will change the the code

Comment: @BasilBourque please see the edit

Comment: have you considered separating your data and ui components? it will make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `instanceof`

I am not an Android programmer, but it looks like your Question is a basic Java question. Are you saying:

> I have an object being returned as the superclass `Object`. But I know in fact that the object is an instance of the `Button` class. How can I refer to it as a `Button` specifically rather than as `Object` generally?

If so, simply cast the object. Going from the more general super-type to the more specific type is [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting).

```
Object o = gridcells.get(0) ;
Button b = ( Button ) o ;
```

Or combine:

```
Button b = ( Button ) gridcells.get(0) ;
```

If not quite sure, do a check with the special operator [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

```
if( gridcells.get(0) instanceof Button ) {
    Button b = ( Button ) gridcells.get(0) ;
}
```

If you are doing much casting in your code, you likely have a design problem. Usually that stems from not understanding the basics of Object-Oriented Programming. But occasionally some casting is in order and cannot be avoided.

See [this similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9174966/642706) for more discussion.

If I am misunderstanding the Question, you may need to re-write your Question.

Comment: @B_C  Glad to help. Study up on casting and [polymorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). Crucial concepts for OOP programming. Once you get past the fancy language you'll see very practical useful applications of the ideas in your coding.